# SQLAlchemy filter by time string

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm struggling with a SQLAlchemy query. I can filter all rows by user ID and Date:

```
for instance in session.query(Datex).filter(Datex.user_id ==1).filter(Datex.date_time == current):
```

However, I'm can't seem to find a clean way to select a subsection of the records. Specifically, I would like to select all rows below string value "14:37". So I would like to select records corresponding to "14:37", "14:42", "14:47" and so on until the last entry. Is this possible? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Is the `time` field(by the way not a good name) a `time` or `text` type? If `text` have you tried `14:37::time` or in general `time::time`(where the naming can get confusing)?

Comment: It's a text type unfortunately.  I'm not familiar with your suggestion so I'll go research it. Thank you.

Comment: Basically `::` is taking the `text` representation and casting it to `time` type. Then you can do the filter on `time` values instead of `text` values. How you do that in SQLAlchemy I don't know.  I gave up trying to figure out how to accomplish the easy in ORM's a while back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [type_coerce](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.type_coerce). Just an example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Time, type_coerce

for rec in session.query(Datex).filter(type_coerce(Datex.time, Time) >= '14:37'):
    # ...
```